# How can I download a Stash repository as a .zip?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I am sort of new to sharing with GitHub and sites like Stash, and I have noticed that there really is no easy way to download a Stash repository without using Git Shell and using some kind of command. With a little research, I found that I likely need to use the git archive command, but I am unsure how I should use this command to download a Stash repository. Could someone please explain how I could do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask your Stash admin to install the [Stash Archive Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.stash.plugin.stash-archive) (by Atlassian Labs for Stash 2.6.0 - 3.5.0)

It will add a "Download" button enable you to download a Git repo without having Git installed locally.

Comment: I do have Git installed locally, I'm just not sure how I can use it to download a Stash repository.